# How to check if system Date/Time is in 12 hours or 24 hours format in J2ME

Tags: java-me, time-format

I am trying to determine if phone's current Locale is set to 12 hours or 24 hours format.
I want to display time in my app in AM/PM only when the device time is in 12 hours format.
In android, it can be obtained using "DateFormat.is24HourFormat()", but in **J2ME** is it possible to retrieve such information ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the system time but you can't get the time format. Maybe there is a system property for the time format but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

If target device is a Nokia you can get it with `System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.timeformat")`, see this and other properties at http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Getting_System_properties_in_MIDP

Comment: Thanks a lot Telmo. But the target device is Samsung. So how to get this info for Samsung device ??

Comment: Sorry @Sumita but I do not know if this is supported on Samsung phones.